# apptoken cannot be blank Xtremepush

Tags: php, api, curl

Hola Estoy intentando conectarme a la API de XTREMEPUSH.
El código de error en PHP :

```
stdClass Object ( [success] => [code] => 400 [message] => apptoken cannot be blank. )
```

A través del programa **Postman** , a través del body le mando el campo **apptoken** , y no tengo problema alguno , pero en PHP no se lo estoy mandando bien(Adjunto código que uso):

```
$url = 'https://external-api.xtremepush.com/api/external/list/profile';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type:application/json',
            '**apptoken**: CODIGO-TOKEN'
        ));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
print_r(json_decode($result));
```

El código que me proporciona esta API es el siguiente:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"apptoken":"YOUR_APPTOKEN"}' https://external-api.xtremepush.com/api/external/list/profile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que mandarlo en el body de la petición POST. Por lo que veo lo estas mandando como un Header

Creo que seria en la parte de `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('apptoken' => 'TOKEN' ));`